# JQuery Drop Down menu wont display drop downs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this [Dynamic Drive Script for a smooth drop down menu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm).

My site with the menu can be seen [here](http://dgtgroup.co.uk/ascofzco/). (the menu is the black bar in the middle).

Everything works fine, except when you hover over the navigation links, the drop down menus do not appear.

I'm not sure what is wrong

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

EDIT: UPDATE
This is the site I am trying to [reproduce](http://www.ascoengineering.co.uk/). The menus on that site appear smoothly.

Comment: Post relevant code in your question, there is just to much to dig through in your page.

Comment: @ Andres Ilich Thanks for replying! I am using the same code that is on this website: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm

Comment: I saw it is working now. Dropdowns are displayed after on hover

Comment: Thanks for replying Umesh! They work but they do not appear 'smoothly' (I have updated my post with more information).

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
.dropdown ul li a:hover ul{visibility:visible; display:block;}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have tried that CSS but it has not effect.

Comment: Hi If i use the following it works: `.dropdown ul li:hover ul{visibility:visible; display:block;}`. However, it doesn't seem to be a smooth menu. (The menu pops up straight away instead of smoothly appearing)

Comment: @ mohana rao adding width 128px, breaks the size of menus.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. I have done this, but it has not effect?